# Simple Json parsing in android 

Tags: android, json, parsing

I got the Json response. I am not able to get the values from the string.my string is

Json_response is

```
{"NameAllList":[{"Current":{"time":"2012-02-21T08:04:21","Name":"abcd"},
    "Next":{"Name":"data1","StartTime":"2012-02-21T08:06:21"}},{"Current":{"time":"2012-02-21T08:14:21","Name":"defg"},
    "Next":{"Name":"data2","StartTime":"2012-02-21T08:24:21"}},{"Current":{"time":"2012-02-21T08:28:21","Name":"ghij"},
    "Next":{"Name":"data3","StartTime":"2012-02-21T08:34:21"}},{"Current":{"time":"2012-02-21T08:40:21","Name":"knmo"},
    "Next":{"Name":"data4","StartTime":"2012-02-21T08:48:21"}}]}
```

and i tried this.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_response);
JSONObject subObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Current");
String name_current =subObj.getString("Name");
```

but i am not able to get the value of "Name". what mistake i have done. provide the link to do the above parsing.

Comment: How can you create string variable without Escape Sequence with such string?

Comment: ya we can't. so i have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing json properly, so you are not able to fetch value of Name. Please note JSON Annotation [] represent JSONArray, and {} respresent JSONObject, so method to get current item's name is:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_response_string);
JSONArray jsonArr=jsonObj.getJSONArray("NameAllList");
String Hora_name_current="";
for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++)
{
     JSONObject obj=jsonArr.get(i);
     try{
           JSONObject subObj = obj.getJSONObject("Current");
           Hora_name_current =subObj.getString("Name");
           break;
     }catch(JSONException ex)
     {

     }



}
```

Answer (score 3):

first of all, your JSON response is having NameAllList as a JSON Array of objects.

So you have to fetch JSON Array first, then you can fetch one-by-one object.

for example:

```
JSONObject jsonString = (new JSONObject(json_response_string));
JSONArray array = jsonString.getJSONArray("NameAllList");

for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
{
   // Retrieve Current object as such
   JSONObject objCurrent = array.getJSONObject("Current");

   // Retrieve Next object as such
   JSONObject objNext = array.getJSONObject("Next");
}
```

Comment: More detailed example i have written: [Android - JSON Parsing example](http://goo.gl/S2TcW). PS: I know i can't do self-promotion of my blog, but i think it makes user's confusion regarding JSON Parsing.

Comment: why can't you self promote your content if it is indeed tightly related to the question?

Comment: @silent we can't do, i know this rule and as per this rule, Moderator is taking care, they will warn you for the same activity, if you still keep doing that activity even after warning, then you will be [**`Suspended and send in the Penalty Box`**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for some period of time. And also that much reputation may be taken back.

Comment: Hi Paresh, Thnks for the response. i have included ur code. its giving me the following error.

"The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

for this line: 
        JSONObject objCurrent = array.getJSONObject("Current");

give a solution!!!

Comment: I have just tried to explain the implementation of JSON Parsing. Please try it yourself, it would be better to understand it perfectly so that you can solve JSON Parsing in future easily.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you're trying to use JSONObject when you should be using JSONArray for the second request.  Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonString = (new JSONObject(json_response_string));
JSONArray array = jsonString.getJSONArray("NameAllList");
```

In your JSON return, "NameAllList is actually an array and needs to be handled as such.  Once you set it to "array", you can then run a for loop and treat it like any other array in Java.

Let me know if that helps.

David

Answer (score -1):

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_response_string);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArrays("NameAllList");